# fs.exists, fs.existsSync - why are they deprecated?

Tags: node.js

I noticed that the official node documentation says something startling about `fs.exists`:

> "fs.exists() is an anachronism and exists only for historical reasons.
>   There should almost never be a reason to use it in your own code.
>
> In particular, checking if a file exists before opening it is an
>   anti-pattern that leaves you vulnerable to race conditions: another
>   process may remove the file between the calls to fs.exists() and
>   fs.open(). Just open the file and handle the error when it's not
>   there."

I understand the suggestion, to open a file and then handle the error if it doesn't exist, but what I don't understand is why the interface is being deprecated rather than the implementation simply changing.

Can anyone explain to me why checking for the existence of a file with an API that is as simple and logical as `fs.exists` is such a bad thing that it should be called an anti-pattern and removed from the node API?

Comment: The [current implementation](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/d8baf8a2a4481940bfed0196308ae6189ca18eee/lib/fs.js#L222) basically does: `function exists(file, cb){ fs.stat(file, function(err, stat){ cb(err); }); }`. So I'm not sure what you mean by `implementation simply changing`. If you absolutely really must know if a file simply exists, why not just use `fs.stat`? It does the same thing and actually returns you more useful info.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - They could alter the implementation under the hood to do a more efficient check that does not require Error generation and resulting performance hit. Using fs.stat() generates an Error which is a noticeable performance hit when hitting many files. I personally prefer to keep fs.exists*() in the API and just refactoring the implementation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799274/node-js-fs-exists-will-be-deprecated-what-to-use-instead/65446343#65446343 for some code alternatives what to use instead of `fs.exists()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it because it's redundant. You can check if a file exists by trying to open it. It will give you `ENOENT` if it doesn't exist:

```
> fs.open('foo', 'r', function(err, fd) {
    ... console.log(err, fd);
    ... 
})
undefined
> { [Error: ENOENT, open 'foo'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'foo' } undefined
```

Comment: You might want to check if a file exists without needing to open it! For example, if you want to prevent a user to create a file whose name already exists, if you want to ensure if a file hasn't been deleted externally, etc.

Comment: @PhiLho If thats the case, you can use `stat` or `statSync` to check if it exists first (see [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback))

Comment: Yes, that's what is said above. Just saying that opening a file to see if it exists is overkill. Unless you really wanted to read it, of course.

Comment: I may also add it is more "expressive" to call exists() rather than open(), exists() in this case makes my intent clear.

Comment: There's a pretty big difference between `if (fs.existsSync('somefile'))` and `var exists = false; try { fs.statSync('somefile'); exists = true; } catch (e) { } if (exists)`. That is, the latter is super annoying. fs.existsSync is a nice wrapper for that.

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to use fs.stat(), because fs.existsSync() has not been deprecated.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path

> **fs.existsSync(path)**
>
> Added in: v0.1.21
> path  | 
> Synchronous version of fs.exists(). Returns true if the file exists, false otherwise.
>
> Note that **fs.exists() is deprecated, but fs.existsSync() is not**. (The callback >parameter to fs.exists() accepts parameters that are inconsistent with other >Node.js callbacks. fs.existsSync() does not use a callback.)

Comment: While this answer is correct, it is preferable to use a non-blocking solution. This article from Node.js explains the difference between blocking & non-blocking filesystem calls. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/

Answer (score 7):

Because of the second paragraph you quoted.

There is no point in checking whether a file exists, because it could always be deleted right after the check.

Comment: Here's a point.  I have a list of files to upload with an API.  I'd like to check if they exist before uploading them.  Now I have to open and close the file which is extra work.  I never needed to open the file in the first place.

Comment: @MichaelCole: Huh? The upload process opens the file.  Even if it exists right before you call upload, there is no guarantee that it will exist when you actually upload it.  This is exactly where there is no point.

Comment: What if I want to check if a directory exists before writing a file to it?

Comment: @Petah: What if someone deletes the directory between those two lines of code?

Comment: @SLaks no different to some one deleting a directory when trying to write a file after creating said directory.

Comment: @Petah: Exactly.  In both cases, you should rely on getting an error.

Comment: I want to check to see if a file exists for a build process. If the output file does not exist or the file's mtime is older than the source, write the file. If exists & the mtime is newer than the source, move on. Very common logic without race conditions.

Answer (score 7):

Being deprecated because it's an anti-pattern according to some. I.e. it's not safe to trust *exists()* and then doing something with the file because the file can be removed in between the exists-call and the doing-something-call.

I agree in the above case. But to me, there is more use of exists(). I place empty dummy files in my temp- and cache directories. When I perform *dangerous* operations, such as removing old files from the cache dir I look for my dummy file to ensure that I'm not operating in the wrong directory. I.e. I just need to confirm that the file is there. Exists suits the bill perfectly for this, but I guess I'll switch to using stat() instead.

Answer (score 1):

existsSync's implementation is like this (v0.10.25):

```
function (path) {
  try {
    nullCheck(path);
    binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

so if you write program like `if(fs.existsSync(thepath)){}`, it is better to change it to `if(fs.statSync(thepath)){}`.

Comment: Not the same. One returns a boolean, the other throws an error!

Answer (score 0):

You can use new install for this one and continue to use it:
https://github.com/imyller/node-fs-exists-nodeback

```
npm install fs-exists-nodeback
```

Answer (score -2):

I was searching for a solution to this issue and found that fs.exists and fs.existsSync was deprecated. This seems to work well in my senario

```
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err,data){
    // the err variable substitutes for the fs.exists callback function variable
    if (!err){
        // do what you planned with the file
        console.log(data)
    }else{
        // handle the non-existence of the file
        console.log('File does not exist!');
    }
});
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) only `fs.exists` has been deprecated, not `fs.existsSync`.