# node.js fs.exists() will be deprecated, what to use instead?

Tags: node.js

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) node.js fs.exists() will be deprecated.
Their reasoning:

> fs.exists() is an anachronism and exists only for historical reasons. There should almost never be a reason to use it in your own code.
>
> In particular, checking if a file exists before opening it is an anti-pattern that leaves you vulnerable to race conditions: another process may remove the file between the calls to fs.exists() and fs.open(). Just open the file and handle the error when it's not there.
>
> fs.exists() will be deprecated.

I am currently using it before moving files, since the fs.rename() seems to quietly overwrite files with the same name in the destination folder.

My question is; what should I use instead to prevent fs.rename() from overwriting the file in the destination folder?
I assume there's a way that I don't know of. Otherwise I don't see a reason for fs.exists() to be deprecated.

Using fs.open() as suggested seems overkill since I don't want to open the file.

---

**Edit**, as per @jfriend00's request for more info about what I'm doing.

I'm making an [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) application where the user can sort files into different directories. It's not a server software, it's intended to run on every day users machines, handling their documents. This is the code so far for moving a file:

```
function moveFile(destIndex){
    var from = queue[currentQueueIndex].path;
    var to = destinations[destIndex].path + path.sep + path.basename(from);
    console.log("[i] Move file (from/to): ");
    console.log(from);
    console.log(to);

    //Check if file exists, if yes: give them the choice to cancel.
    fs.stat(to, function (err, stats) {
        if (err){
            move(from, to);
        } else {
            var confirmed = confirm("File already exists, will overwrite.");
            if (confirmed) {
                move(from, to);
            }
        }
    });
    next(); //Show the next file to the user
}

function move(from, to){
    fs.rename(from, to, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('[i] Move successful');
        queue[currentQueueIndex].path = to;
        queue[currentQueueIndex].moved = true;
    });
}
```

After the first comment, the part starting with fs.stat, I check whether the file I'm about to create with fs.rename already exists. I guess this is subject to race conditions, but I can't find that fs.rename handles duplicates in any way.
Since this application is intended for "home computing", I don't think the scenario where a file disappears between the stat check and the rename is likely to happen. But still, the more potential problems I can avoid, the better.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to use `fs.exists()` for?  We need a few more details about the sequence of your code before we could suggest something that is not susceptible to race conditions?  The point is that any substitute that just checks for the existence and then carries out an action based on that knowledge is subject to race conditions and there is likely a better way to code it.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I have added what I'm doing to the main question, as well as the code for it.

Comment: In the case of an end-user prompt on a somewhat single-user computer, the resulting race condition is probably not concerning.  The real answer would be a version of `fs.rename()` that would not overwrite the target, so you can call it that way and only if it fails to do the rewrite because the target exists, do you then prompt and change the argument to `fs.rename()` to allow overwrite.  This would never overwrite without first prompting.  But, I would agree - probably not needed in this type of use case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [io.js docs](https://iojs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) mention the use of `fs.stat()` or `fs.access()` in place of `fs.exists()`.

Comment: fs.stat() looks promising, but when I try to use it `var stat = fs.statSync(file);` I get an ENOENT error on files that doesn't exist. How do I handle that?

Comment: I got it working. I put the rename function inside the stat function, reverse of the [4th example here](https://iojs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system), which allowed me to use stat and not statSync. Although `if(error) doSomething();` feels a bit weird.

Comment: @Blargmode - It sounds like what you're doing is still subject to a race condition.

Comment: @jfriend00 Technically it is, but the `RENAME_NOREPLACE` flag was only added at the [beginning of last year](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/1/8/641) and is not available for all file system types and is Linux-specific. Also, node/io.js does not provide a binding for `renameat2()` which is the syscall you'd pass that flag to.

Comment: I've asked the OP exactly what they're doing because I think we can offer them better advice on avoiding a race condition than just using a substitute for `fs.exists()` that is also vulnerable to the same race condition.  In this case, I think there's a better answer than just offering them this work-around if the OP will share more info on what their code looks like and what exactly they are trying to do.

Answer (score 21):

Use fs.existsSync().

fs.existsSync() has not been deprecated.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path

> **fs.existsSync(path)**
>
> Added in: v0.1.21
> path  | 
> Synchronous version of fs.exists(). Returns true if the file exists, false otherwise.
>
> Note that **fs.exists() is deprecated, but fs.existsSync() is not**. (The callback >parameter to fs.exists() accepts parameters that are inconsistent with other >Node.js callbacks. fs.existsSync() does not use a callback.)

Comment: Seems odd to deprecate the function rather than just changing the function interface to be consistent with other Node.js callbacks.

Comment: changing the function signature would potentially break existing code

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example using `fs.access` (in older Node versions, use `fs.stat` instead of `fs.access`), but handling errors correctly as well:

```js
import { access } from 'node:fs/promises';

async function fileExists(filename) {
    try {
        await access(filename);
        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is neat...

Answer (score 4):

Here is example by using `fs.stat`:-

```
fs.stat('mycustomfile.csv', function (err, stats) {
   console.log(stats);//here we got all information of file in stats variable
   if (err) {
       return console.error(err);
   }
     fs.unlink('mycustomfile.csv',function(err){
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('file deleted successfully');
   });  
});
```

Comment: Perhaps I want to handle the scenario where the file doesn't exist differently than if some other error occurred. How can I handle that?

Answer (score 4):

```
const exists = !!(await fs.promises.stat(filename).catch(() => null))
```

Comment: thanks for that oneliner but bloody hell, why are they butchering the standard modules this way