# Javascript,Nodejs: search for a specific word string in files

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string, file

i'm trying to make an app that searches for all files 
contains a specified string under the current directory/subdirectory.

as i understand it means i need to create a read stream, loop it, load the read data to an array, if the word found give __filename, dirname and if ! not found message.

unfortunately, i could not make it work...
any clue?

```js
var path = require('path'),
 fs=require('fs');

function fromDir(startPath,filter,ext){

    if (!fs.existsSync(startPath)){
        console.log("no dir ",startPath);
        return;
    };
    
    var files=fs.readdirSync(startPath);
    let found = files.find((file) => {
        let thisFilename = path.join(startPath, file);
        let stat = fs.lstatSync(thisFilename);
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(fs);
        var readline = require('readline');
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            fromDir(thisFilename, filename,readline, ext);



        } else {
            if (path.extname(createReadStream) === ext && path.basename(thisFilename, ext) === filename) {
                return true;
        }
        }
        });

       

            console.log('-- your word has found on : ',filename,__dirname);
        }
     
    if (!found) { 
        console.log("Sorry, we didn't find your term");
    }

    }
    
    fromDir('./', process.argv[3], process.argv[2]);
```

Comment: You require readline, but you don't seem to be using it [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline). Also, you could [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) something like `grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'pattern'` instead.

Comment: `fs.existsSync() ... fs.readdirSync()` [is an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532820/fs-exists-fs-existssync-why-are-they-deprecated/28532866), as it introduces a (rare, but possible) race condition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because not everything was included in the question, I made an assumption:

> We are looking for full words (if that's not the case, replace the regex with a simple `indexOf()`).

Now, I've split the code into two functions - to make it both more readable and easier to recursively find the files.

**Synchronous version:**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function searchFilesInDirectory(dir, filter, ext) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        console.log(`Specified directory: ${dir} does not exist`);
        return;
    }

    const files = getFilesInDirectory(dir, ext);

    files.forEach(file => {
        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(file);
        
        // We want full words, so we use full word boundary in regex.
        const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + filter + '\\b');
        if (regex.test(fileContent)) {
            console.log(`Your word was found in file: ${file}`);
        }
    });
}

// Using recursion, we find every file with the desired extention, even if its deeply nested in subfolders.
function getFilesInDirectory(dir, ext) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        console.log(`Specified directory: ${dir} does not exist`);
        return;
    }

    let files = [];
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
        const filePath = path.join(dir, file);
        const stat = fs.lstatSync(filePath);
        
        // If we hit a directory, apply our function to that dir. If we hit a file, add it to the array of files.
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            const nestedFiles = getFilesInDirectory(filePath, ext);
            files = files.concat(nestedFiles);
        } else {
            if (path.extname(file) === ext) {
                files.push(filePath);
            }
        }
    });

    return files;
}
```

**Async version - because `async` is cool:**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const fsReaddir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
const fsReadFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const fsLstat = util.promisify(fs.lstat);

async function searchFilesInDirectoryAsync(dir, filter, ext) {  
    const found = await getFilesInDirectoryAsync(dir, ext);

    for (file of found) {
        const fileContent = await fsReadFile(file);

        // We want full words, so we use full word boundary in regex.
        const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + filter + '\\b');
        if (regex.test(fileContent)) {
            console.log(`Your word was found in file: ${file}`);
        }
    };
}

// Using recursion, we find every file with the desired extention, even if its deeply nested in subfolders.
async function getFilesInDirectoryAsync(dir, ext) {
    let files = [];
    const filesFromDirectory = await fsReaddir(dir).catch(err => {
        throw new Error(err.message);
    });

    for (let file of filesFromDirectory) {
        const filePath = path.join(dir, file);
        const stat = await fsLstat(filePath);

        // If we hit a directory, apply our function to that dir. If we hit a file, add it to the array of files.
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            const nestedFiles = await getFilesInDirectoryAsync(filePath, ext);
            files = files.concat(nestedFiles);
        } else {
            if (path.extname(file) === ext) {
                files.push(filePath);
            }
        }
    };

    return files;
}
```

If you have not worked with / understand async/await yet, it is a great step to take and learn it as soon as possible. Trust me, you will love not seeing those ugly callbacks again!

**UPDATE:**
As you pointed in comments, you want it to execute the function after running `node` process on the file. You also want to pass the function parameters as `node`'s arguments.

To do that, at the end of your file, you need to add:

```
searchFilesInDirectory(process.argv[2], process.argv[3], process.argv[4]);
```

This extracts our arguments and passes them to the function.

With that, you can call our process like so (example arguments):

```
node yourscriptname.js ./ james .txt
```

Personally, if I were to write this, I would leverage the beauty of asynchronous code, and Node.js's `async / await`.

**As a very side note:**

You can easily improve readability of your code, if you add proper formatting to it. Don't get me wrong, it's not terrible - but it can be improved:

1. Use spaces OR newlines after commas.
2. Use spaces around equality operators and arithmetic operators.

As long as you are consistent with formatting, everything looks much better.

Comment: Hi, your edit to the code is error free syntax wise, but still i cannot find any word in files with it. 
any ideas why? thank you

Comment: Could you show me how exactly are you using it? I tested it and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: lets say i have txt files in a subfolder named 232,and i want to find the one that has the word "james" in it.  i want to type node search txt james and the console.log to show me which file(s) contain this string.

Comment: I understand that all. But You need to be more specific on what exactly is happening - when I run it locally on my PC, it finds words just fine, no matter the amount of files or subfolders. I've tested with both static file paths and relative ones.

Comment: Are you running it like this? 

`searchFilesInDirectory('./', 'james', '.txt');`

Comment: `searchFilesInDirectory('C:\\something\\more\etc', 'james', '.txt');` should work as well.

Comment: Oh. You cannot do that. `node` command expects a javascript file to be passed to it.

Comment: i'm getting this messge: https://imgur.com/a/EdkaL

i want it to be used like that: https://imgur.com/a/Pj1Nb

Comment: What you can do though, is inside the file specify the three function parameters as node's `process.argv[index]`. That way, you will be able to execute it like: `node myjavascriptfile.js filepath filter extension`

Comment: Dziękuję bardzo

Comment: You shouldn't use `fs.exists[Sync]`, particularly in your asynchronous version, since [it's an anti-pattern that introduces a race condition.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532820/fs-exists-fs-existssync-why-are-they-deprecated/28532866)