# Why node.js `fs.existsSync` doesn't work well when wrapped in promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs

I'm writing a function `createFile` to create a file in a directory unless it already exists. I'm using Node.js native `fs` package to do all file operations. I wanted to make my function asynchronous so I wrapped all `fs` functions in promises:

```
function writeFilePromise(writePath, textContent) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.writeFile(writePath, textContent, (err) => {
        reject();
      });
      resolve();
    });
  }

  function mkDirPromise(dir) {
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.mkdir(path.join(constants.FILES_STORAGE_DIR, dir), (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
      resolve();
    }));
  }
```

Then I wanted to also wrap `fs.existsSync` in promise in order to complete my function but wrapping it resulted in occasional incorrect behavior, namely, if a directory for the file didn't exist and I wanted to create one the directory would be created empty without the file. Through debugging I found that only synchronous `fs.existsSync` would work **always**.
This the function code:

```
function createFile(dir, fileName, httpMethod, textContent) {
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
      const searchPath = path.join(ROOT_DIR, dir, fileName);
      if (httpMethod === POST && fs.existsSync(searchPath)) {
        reject();
      } else {
        const fileExistsStatus = fs.existsSync(path.join(ROOT_DIR, dir));
        (async function fsOperations() {
          try {
            if (!fileExistsStatus) {
              await mkDirPromise(dir);
            }
            await writeFilePromise(searchPath, textContent);
            resolve();
          } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
        }());
      }
    }));
  }
```

What am I missing and how can I turn my function into truly asynchronous?

Comment: Your question is confusing. I think you could make this clearer.

I *think* that you are wanting to use `fs.exists` instead of `fs.existsSync`, but you've used the `existsSync` throughout your entire post making no reference to the async version.  Can you update your post to include the code sample that *isn't* working?

Comment: @Gary fs.exists is deprecated.

Comment: You really shouldn't use either one.  Just trying to read/write from the file and handle the errors.

The problem with `exists` is that the value you get back might be wrong by the time that you try to use it (things can edit the files other than your app). (edited to remove incorrect claim about existsSync being deprecated)

Comment: @Gary Checking that a file exists seems ok to me, because there can be numerous reason why read/write fails. Yes, that's a good point about exists, existsSync has less chance to fail. Any way, the problem here is incorrect promisification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> occasional incorrect behavior, namely, if a directory for the file didn't exist and I wanted to create one the directory would be created empty without the file

This may be caused by incorrect implementations of `writeFilePromise` and especially `mkDirPromise`. `fs.writeFile` and `fs.mkdir` are asynchronous but a promise is resolved synchronously. It should be:

```
  function writeFilePromise(writePath, textContent) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.writeFile(writePath, textContent, (err) => {
        if (err)
          reject(err);
        else
          resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  function mkDirPromise(dir) {
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.mkdir(path.join(constants.FILES_STORAGE_DIR, dir), (err) => {
        if (err)
          reject(err);
        else
          resolve();
      });
    }));
  }
```

This is what `util.promisify` is for:

```
const writeFilePromise = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
```

Even then this is a wheel reinvention, because there are already third-party packages that do this and even more, namely `fs-extra`.

`createFile` has poor control flow and makes use of promise construction antipattern. Since it uses `async..await`, it should be:

```
async function createFile(dir, fileName, httpMethod, textContent) {
  const searchPath = path.join(ROOT_DIR, dir, fileName);
  if (httpMethod === POST && fs.existsSync(searchPath)) {
    throw new Error();
  } else {
    const fileExistsStatus = fs.existsSync(path.join(ROOT_DIR, dir));
    if (!fileExistsStatus) {
      await mkDirPromise(dir);
    }
    await writeFilePromise(searchPath, textContent);
  }
}
```

It should be mentioned that `existsSync` is stable API method, it's acceptable to use it to check if a file exists. As [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path) states,

> Note that fs.exists() is deprecated, but fs.existsSync() is not. (The callback parameter to fs.exists() accepts parameters that are inconsistent with other Node.js callbacks. fs.existsSync() does not use a callback.)

Comment: I upvoted because this does have some good suggestions, but fundamentally I feel like it doesn't address [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28532820/1541563).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks. I think there is no issue. There is a common misconception that both `exists` and `existsSync` are deprecated, while it's only `exists` that is deprecated because its callback is non-conforming because it's not error-first. `existsSync` is blocking but checking if a file exists is one of few scenarios when this is beneficial.

Comment: I understand that the asynchronous form is the only deprecated one, but just because the synchronous form is blocking doesn't mean another process couldn't modify the permissions for the file in those few hundred microseconds in between ;)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's correct, there's non-zero probability that a check if file exists will be false positive or negative, it's just lower with existsSync. I don't think it's a real problem here, just a good practice that can be used as a rule of thumb. I updated the answer with a clarification on exists vs existsSync. IIRC, I almost fell into same pitfall a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you've structured `writeFilePromise` and `mkDirPromise` so that they will always `resolve`, and never `reject`.  Since `fs.writeFile`
and `fs.mkdir` are asynchronous, the thread immediately moves on to `resolve()` once they've kicked off.  I think what you meant was...

```
function writeFilePromise(writePath, textContent) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile(writePath, textContent, (err) => {
            if (err) reject();
            else resolve();
        });
    });
}

function mkDirPromise(dir) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.mkdir(path.join(constants.FILES_STORAGE_DIR, dir), (err) => {
            if (err) reject();
            else resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

In terms of `fs.exists`, that's been depricated, so I wouldn't recommend using it.  Instead, try `fs.access`:

```
function accessPromise(dir) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.access(dir, (err) => {
            if (err) reject();
            else resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Finally, try adjusting where you use the `async` function declaration, to ensure you're synchronizing your code correctly:

```
async function createFile(dir, fileName, httpMethod, textContent) {
    const searchPath = path.join(ROOT_DIR, dir, fileName);
    if (httpMethod === POST && await accessPromise(searchPath)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        const fileExistsStatus = await accessPromise(path.join(ROOT_DIR, dir));
        try {
            if (!fileExistsStatus) {
                await mkDirPromise(dir);
            }
            await writeFilePromise(searchPath, textContent);
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to use `await createFile(dir, fileName, httpMethod, textContent)` when calling that function.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider rejecting with something meaningful instead of just `reject()`

Since you are thinking with async and promise, I don't recommend using `fs.xxxSync()` functions. Also, `fs.exists` is deprecated, try using `fs.stat()`.

I guess you will only create the file if the HTTP method is POST, but the file will always be created when HTTP method is not POST in the current if-else logic.

It is unnecessary to create an immediately-invoked async function.

Try this:

```
function createFile(dir, fileName, httpMethod, textContent) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const searchPath = path.join(ROOT_DIR, dir, fileName);
        if (httpMethod !== POST) {
            return reject(new Error('Invalid HTTP method'));
        }
        fs.exists(searchPath, (exists) => {
            if (exists) {
                return reject(new Error('Already exists'));
            }
            fs.exists(path.join(ROOT_DIR, dir), async (exists) => {
                try {
                    if (!exists) {
                        await mkDirPromise(dir);
                    }
                    await writeFilePromise(searchPath, textContent);
                    resolve();
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```